# laravel generate pdf of a view with js and external css

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, pdf, dompdf

i have a table which contains some rows of results, user can see the result in details by open any row and there is download option option as well. which supposed to be download the full result of that row.so basically i want download a view containing external css and js, i am using dompdf package but its only downloading/streaming the html with data not my scripts that should be execute and css.

//in my controller

```
use PDF;
public function createPDF($id = 5) {
        // retreive all records from db
        .... defining data variables

            $data = [
                'user_request' => $user_request,
                'feature_percentile_scores' => $feature_percentile_scores,
                'transcript_file' => $transcript_file,
                'transcript_text' => $transcript_text,
                'response_length' => $response_length,
                'functional_text' => $functional_text,
            ];
      // share data to view
      view()->share('user.result',$data);
      $pdf = PDF::loadView('user.result', $data);

      // download PDF file with download method
      return $pdf->download('pdf_file.pdf');
}
```

it's working but not rendering the external css and javascript that i have used. Please help, is there any way to generate a pdf  of rendered view? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use **MPdf** instead of **"dompdf"** . If it's not working then use Inline/Onpage css & js on the pdf template.

Comment: Sorry i have edited the comment css and js on the same email template. External script support isn't much available many packages. So, you may use on page css and js or you may use css and js on extended template (like app.blade.php in laravel) that you add in any view page.

Comment: actually my scripts already available in same view at the end of the html , css is fixed when use inline but js is not executing

Comment: what type of js operation you have used there?

Comment: i am sending the text file of a speech and using javascript i am counting and displaying the words, functional word count and so many things so js is important for his view

Comment: Sorry that won't work as far as i know. While rendering view in pdf it only initiates the static data or design and the data passes to that view while rendering. 
If you mostly need JS to work out there you may use jsPdf library to export pdf but jsPdf isn't so much developer friendly.